# Stopping/Starting Windows services

Tags: windows, service, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have four Windows services which start up automatically when the machine starts. Thereafter, I want to restart those services every 8 hours in a particular order.

e.g. Stop s1,s2,s3,s4 and than restart them in some other order like s4,s3,s2,s1. The condition is that I should wait for each service to stop completely before I stop another one.

I would want to write a .BAT or some script. Is it possible to define a scheduled task for 8 hours? This is not there in Advanced tasks. Can I do it using Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to restart the services?

Comment: They all get hung after running for almost 12-14 hours. 8 hours is a logical point of start for the new shift to work. We are working on getting this fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a batch file:

```
net stop service4
net stop service3
net stop service2

net start service2
net start service3
net start service4
```

Assuming you are using xp/2003 or above you could create a scheduled task to run the batch file. Assuming you want to repeat the task every 8 hours, pick a time for it to run, then on the properties of the scheduled task, schedule tab > advanced... > repeat task. 
Change it to repeat every 8 hours.

Comment: +1. It doesn't get any easier than this.